# declare extern variable within a C function?

Tags: c, declaration, extern, variable-declaration

I define a variable in a C file: `int x`, and I know I should use `extern int x` to declare it in other files if I want to use it in other files.

My question is: where should I declare it in other files?

1. Outside of all functions,

   ```
   // in file a.c:
   int x;

   // in file b.c:
   extern int x;
   void foo() { printf("%d\n", x); }
   ```
2. within the function(s) that will use it?

   ```
   // in file b.c:
   void foo() {
      extern int x;
      printf("%d\n", x);
   }
   ```

My doubts are:

- Which one is correct?, or
- Which is preferred if both are correct?

Comment: See [What are `extern` variables in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c/) for an extensive disquisition on the subject.  The declaration should be in a header so that it is only written once — this means you can change it much more easily than if there are twenty copies of the declaration in twenty functions in six source files. Both `a.c` and `b.c` include the header — it's included in `a.c` to ensure that the declaration matches the definition. Both variants that you show are 'technically correct'; they work as you want.  Neither is desirable, though.

Answer (score 20):

1. Both are correct.
2. Which one is preferred depend on the scope of variable's use.

   - If you only use it in one function, then declare it in the function.

     ```
     void foo() 
     {
          extern int x;   <--only used in this function.
          printf("%d",x);   
     }
     ```
   - If it is used by more than one function in file, declare it as a global value.

     ```
     extern int x;   <-- used in more than one function in this file
     void foo()
     {
         printf("in func1 :%d",x);   
     }    
     void foo1() 
     {
         printf("in func2 :%d",x);   
     }
     ```

Comment: Please clear my doubt: for extern variables declared inside function, how is this any different from automatic storage class? Is the extern variable has static lifetime scope?

Answer (score 6):

Suppose if you declare within function:

```
// in file b.c:
void foo() {
    extern int x;
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
void foo_2() {
    printf("%d\n", x);  <-- "can't use x here"
}
```

then `x` is visible locally inside function `foo()` only and if I have any other function say `foo_2()`, I can't access `x` inside `foo_2()`.

Whereas if you declares `x` outside before all function then it would be visible/accessible globally in complete file (all functions).

```
  // in file b.c:
  extern int x;
  void foo() { printf("%d\n", x); }
  void foo_2() { printf("%d\n", x); }  <--"visible here too"
```

So if you need `x` in only single function then you can just declare inside that function but if `x` uses in several function then declare `x` outside all function (your first suggestion).

Comment: Thanks Yulian, Lidong and Grijesh. I think I got all the answer that I want. :)

Answer (score 5):

you can use another technique in the way you can declare a variable with the specifier extern.

```
// in file a.c:
int x;
```

---

```
// in file b.h  //   make a header file and put it in 
                //   the same directory of your project and every
                //   time you want to declare this variable 
                //   you can just INCLUDE this header file as shown in b.c
extern int x;
```

---

```
// in file b.c:
#include "b.h"
void foo() { printf("%d\n", x); }
```